# This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source

Tags: javascript, websocket, media-source

I'm trying to readStream an mp4 file  and send chunks back to the client. I'm using the mediasource api. The code is failing on:

```
 sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(mediaChunkBuffer));
```

with the error: **This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source**

I'm able to append the first chunk this is done by calling initialMediaChunk(). for all subsequent chunks, i'm calling subsequentMediaChunk(). I get a MediaSource Api error.

I notice after the first chunk, the mediaSource sourceclose event is called, making the mediaSource.readystate set to false, for subsequent chunks.

```
let mediaSource;
let mediaQueue = [];
let mediaChunkBuffer; 

function subsequentMediaChunk(dataObj)
{
    mediaChunkBuffer = new Uint8Array(dataObj.data.dataChunk).buffer;
    if (sourceBuffer.updating || mediaQueue.length > 0) {
        mediaQueue.push(mediaChunkBuffer);
    } else {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(mediaChunkBuffer));  // failing here
    }
}
function initialMediaChunk(dataObj){
    mediaChunkBuffer = new Uint8Array(dataObj.data.dataChunk).buffer;
    var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

         if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
         mediaSource = new MediaSource();
         mediaSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
         console.log(e);
         });
         mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', function(e) {
         console.log(e);
         })
         mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
             var mime = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
             sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mime);

             var file = new Blob([mediaChunkBuffer], {type: type});
             var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = function(e) {
                sourceBuffer.addEventListener('onupdate', function() { // Note: Have tried 'updateend'
                    if (mediaQueue.length > 0 && !sourceBuffer.updating) {

                      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(mediaQueue.shift()));
                    }
                });
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));
              }

              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

          }, false);
         let videoElement = $("#" + loadVideoFileName).find('video');
         videoElement.attr("src",window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource));

       }
}
```

Comment: facing the same problem!

Comment: @MX-Qulin did you later fixed it?